# Why does my code run different on google chrome inspection?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have made a responsive navbar with html, css and basic js, that changes according to the width of the screen.

Although the code works perfectly and the navbar is responsive while resizing the window (that i preview my code to), when I test it with Google Chrome Inspect to see how it looks on other devices (phones, tablet, etc) it doesn't work, even though the width is smaller than the max-width i have set:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links li a {
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code and desktop CSS as well?

Comment: My suspicion is that you don’t have a viewport link in your head element. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />